# Contacting a SQL DB through Javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to build a website in html5 & javascript.  I want the website to pull data from a database and display in a list on website.

Is there a way of doing this

Comment: with the html and javascript  ,you can just use texts for database , but you cant write some datas , just read from txts , good luck :D

Comment: Hey Osman Erdi.  I dont need to add to the database just pull data from it. when you say use texts for database what do you mean?

Comment: create a .txt file and read contents from into txt file with javascript and append it to html

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** want to do that, for many reasons. Have a back-end (server-side) dealing with database connections and make your client-side communicate with your server. This is the correct architecture you want to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the website used to function with asp.net.  I am told, due to Apple products/browser that the website needed to be revamped to support that in html5, javascript to show all functionality.  On the old website there was a bit of server side interaction, so html5 and javascript are being pushed